# How to prove $\ln N\ge 1/2+1/3+1/4+\cdots+1/N$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt$. I want to show that $\ln N\ge 1/2+1/3+1/4+\cdots+1/N$. The hint is Riemann sum, but I can only get $\int_1^N\frac{1}{t}dt>1\cdot\ln 1+1\cdot\ln2+\cdots+1\cdot\ln N$ (use the fact that integral $\ge$ lower sum). How to prove that? Or is my attempt wrong?

And also for $2^k$, how to show that $1/2+1/3+\cdots+1/N\ge k/2$?

Comment: For $2^k$, take $\frac 12$ and add $\frac 13+\frac 14\ge \frac 14+\frac 14$ then add $\frac 15+\frac 16+\frac 17+\frac 18\ge \frac 18+\frac 18+\frac 18+\frac 18$ and so on...

Comment: "*but I can only get $\int_1^N\frac{1}{t}dt>1\cdot \ln 1 + 1\cdot ln 2 + \dots + 1\cdot \ln N$*"  How did you make the change to $\ln$'s there?  Consider breaking the integral up into rectangles each of width $1$.  For integers $x$ one has $\int\limits_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{x-1} \int\limits_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{t}dt$.  Now, on each interval, take the smallest value to describe the whole interval... The smallest value is in terms of a fraction, not in terms of a logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $f(t)$ is decreasing, 
$\int_n^{n+1} f(x)\; dx \ge f(n+1)$.  Add these for $n$ from $1$ to $N-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1x\ge\frac1{\lceil x\rceil}$$ implies

$$\int_1^n\frac1 x\,dx=\ln n\ge\int_1^n\frac1{\lceil x\rceil}\,dx=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1k.$$

---

By the same reasoning with the floor,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k\ge\ln n.$$

Answer (score -3):

for some function $f(x)$:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\ge\sum_{x=a}^bf(x)$$
so we know that:
$$\int_1^N\frac1xdx\ge\sum_{i=1}^N\frac1i$$
and we know that:
$$\int_1^N\frac1xdx=\ln(N)$$

Comment: The summation in the second display equations starts $\color{red}{1 + } \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots$.

Comment: yes ideally we want the summation to start from $i=2$

Comment: Not only do we *ideally* want the summation to start from $i=2$, we *must* have the summation start from $i=2$.  Breaking it into rectangles, if we use the highest value for each rectangle, then the resulting summation would be *bigger*, not smaller.  You actually have $\int_1^N\frac{1}{x}dx \color{red}{\leq}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{i}$.  For simple example, take $N=1$.  The left hand side is equal to zero.  The right hand side is equal to $1$.

Comment: Your first line is not true either.  It depends on whether or not the function $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing or decreasing or neither.